# Differentiate between Map[String,String] and Map[String,Object]

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have two different maps that are created in my project. I have used type alias for both.

```
type alias1 = Map[String, ScalaObject]
type alias2 = Map[String, String]
```

I have a match-case situation where I want to differentiate between the two because different operations need to happen on both.

val obj: T = fromJson[T](jacksonMapper, json)

```
obj match {
  case _: alias1 => operation1()
  case _: alias2 => operation2()
  case _ => obj
}
```

Any idea how to differentiate the two?

Comment: You can't, due type erasure both types become the same class in runtime _(where the pattern match is being executed)_. You may use a simple **ADT** or a **typeclass**.

Comment: Can you give an example pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two key concepts to understand why the two maps cannot be differentiated at runtime are

- *type erasure* where compile-time parameteriseed type `Map[String, String]` becomes runtime class `Map`
- *pattern matching* translates to runtime `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` calls

Consider the following simplified example

```
case class Foo[T](i: T) 

val fooInt = Foo[Int](42)
val fooStr = Foo[String]("")

fooInt.isInstanceOf[Foo[String]]
// val res0: Boolean = true
```

Note how `isInstanceOf` could not check at runtime what was the compile-time type parameter `T` and so it cannot differentiate between `fooInt` and `fooStr`. Effectively the best we can do is something like

```
fooInt.isInstanceOf[Foo[_]]
```

where the underscore `_` serves to communicate the fact of type erasure.

Next consider how the following pattern match

```
(fooInt: Any) match { case str: Foo[String] => "oops :(" }
// val res1: String = oops :(
```

effectively becomes something like

```
if (fooInt.isInstanceOf[Foo[String]]) "oops :("
```

which again due to type erasure incorrectly evaluates to `"oops :("`.

An alternative approach is to try to do as much as possible at compile-time before type arguments are discarded. *Typeclasses* can be thought of as kind of compile-time pattern matching that happens before type erasure.

Answer (score 4):

**ADT** would be to create a sealed trait with some case classes for each case; so one for a **Map[String, String]** and other for **Map[String, ScalaObject]** and you can pattern match on the case classes.
So like this:

```
sealed trait MyType extends Product with Serializable
final case class ObjMap(data: Map[String, ScalaObject]) extends MyType
final case class StrMap(data: Map[String, String]) extends MyType

val obj: MyType = ???
obj match {
  case ObjMap(_) => operation1()
  case StrMap(_) => operation2()
}
```

The **Typeclass** approach may be too complex for this.